# How to do a tekken/street fighter like slider/bar

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a health bar which transition from healthValueX to healthValueY over time. Currently I am decreasing the value like this:

```
void Update ()
{
    myVar-= 100 * Time.deltaTime;
    slider.value = myVar;
}
```

and there is 2 methods which I call on press to manage the slider in addition.

```
void addHealth()
{
    myVar+=250; //Harcoded for the short question
}
void forceRemoveHealth()
{
    myVar-=250; //Hardcoded for the short question
}
```

I like the transition in the `Update` it looks good. But when I manage a huge change for example in `addHealth()` or `forceRemoveHealth()` I would to color the gap and then to transition instead of going from 300 health directly to 50 for example.

The tricky part is that I do both - decrease every frame and want to support a bigger decrease based on input. What's the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [Mathf.Lerp()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html) to interpolate between 300 and 50 for example below:

```
public float start;
public float end;

// Change in units/sec.
public float speed = 1.0F;

private float startTime;

// Total distance between the start and end.
private float length = Mathf.Abs(start - end);

public healthBarLength = start;

void Start()
{
    startTime = Time.time;
}

void Update()
{
    float delta = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
    float fracDelta = delta / length;
    healthBarLength = Vector3.Lerp(start, end, fracDelta);
}
```

Of course, this is just for Lerping a number from when the game starts, you'll need to turn it into a function/coroutine.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I want to support both overtime and exprisit change of the slider with coloring of the change.

Comment: Then you need to clarify in the question

Comment: If you want to change the  colour of something, this still works, just lerp between the colours